# Create haskell function with different return value

Tags: function, haskell

I want to create Haskell function with different return value from its parameter, example:
I want function `isOdd 3` return value either `True` or `False`.
I've tried

```
isOdd :: Integer -> Bool
isOdd x = (if x mod 2 == 0 False else True)
```

but it returns an error, can anybody help me? Also, is there a tutorial about functions in Haskell? I can't find a good tutorial about function in haskell.

Comment: if (pred) then ... else ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
isOdd :: Integer -> Bool
isOdd x = (if x mod 2 == 0 False else True)
```

You don't need the parens:

```
isOdd :: Integer -> Bool
isOdd x = if x mod 2 == 0 False else True
```

You missed out `then`:

```
isOdd :: Integer -> Bool
isOdd x = if x mod 2 == 0 then False else True
```

As you are using `mod` as an operator, you must surround it with backticks:

```
isOdd :: Integer -> Bool
isOdd x = if x `mod` 2 == 0 then False else True
```

That works.

Furthermore, you can write `if blah then False else True` more simply as `not (blah)`:

```
isOdd :: Integer -> Bool
isOdd x = not (x `mod` 2 == 0)
```

Even more simply:

```
isOdd :: Integer -> Bool
isOdd x = x `mod` 2 /= 0
```

Please note: this is practically the same as the standard [`odd`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3aodd) function.

---

Which tutorials have you tried?

Learn You A Haskell has a [chapter introducing functions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#babys-first-functions).

Comment: thank you :) i forget to add then in this question, and i dont really understand about importance backticks, difference between operator and function

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `mod` isn't infix. Additionally, in Haskell if statements work like this

```
if cond then expr1 else expr2
```

Notice the `then`.

You should use `mod` like this `mod x 2`. However you can make it infix like this:

```
x `mod` 2
```

On a side not

```
x `mod` 2 /= 0
```

Is much easier to read than the whole if statement.

---

As far as tutorials: [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) is a good start. For a more in depth coverage [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/) is excellent.

If you just want to find a function then [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is your friend.

Comment: thank you i just find that tutorial, i think i dont really understand concept in prefix and infix and importance of backticks

Comment: Prefix means before so `func args` the backticks are a special trick for functions with two arguments that let you write `arg1 'func' arg2` just for clarity. There is no difference between `mod x 2` and `x 'mod' 2` except the second one is perhaps easier to understand

Comment: oh thx for the explanation :) how about class constraint? i didnt really get it